# Widgets preview not working - Message send failure for relaunch

Tags: xcode, swiftui, widget

I'm trying to add a simple new widget target to my existing project.
But before i'm adding even 1 line of code, and i click on the preview button i see the following error:
[image]

[image]

Cannot preview in this file -- Message send failure for relaunch

MessageSendFailure: Message send failure for relaunch

==================================

| RemoteHumanReadableError |
| --- |
| ProcessError: Failed to launch widget extension: The operation couldn’t be completed. (CHSErrorDomain error 1050.) |

As much as i understand, there is an issue with the Apple M1 silicon chip, the same one that i have.
but it's not make sense that everyone with M1 are not able to work with widgets.
I tried the following steps already:

1. clear all xCode cache & derived data.
2. restart my computer.
3. check/uncheck the "Copy only when installing" checkbox in the "Embed App Extensions".
4. check/uncheck "Include Configuration Intent" checkbox in the widgets creation form on xCode.

But nothing works.

Update: i tried to do the same thing with none M1 macbook chip and it works fine. so the issue is related to the M1 chip for sure.
any ideas if there is something to do about it?

Comment: Do you have select "App Groups" in target=>signing & capabilities???

Comment: No. but in what way "App Groups" can help to the preview to render?

Comment: Hey, were you able to figure out how to resolve this issue, I am having the same problem.

Comment: @JArango i didn't try actually, but let's hope there is a fix in the next big release of Xcode 14.